# How to uncheck selected radio input onChange with react to reset current showing data?

Tags: reactjs

I have created multiple Radio buttons options. For each radio button based on the value date, I would display different users based on availability.

Now, when I select one or the second radio button it will display different users.

But for some reason, the "CHECKED" value will stay whenever I switch to another radio input option. It will display different data but I would like to reset these mapped (currentConsult) values to display none.

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// import ConsultSelect from './ConsultSelect';

const Appointment = (props) => {
    const { loading, data, consultSelect } = props;
    const [consult, setConsult] = useState([]);
    const [filteredConsult, setFilteredConsult] = useState([]);
    const [currentConsult, setCurrentConsult] = useState([]);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
        selected: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setConsult(data);

        if (consultSelect === 'consult_business') {
            setFilteredConsult(consult.consult_business);
        }

        if (consultSelect === 'consult_strategy') {
            setFilteredConsult(consult.consult_strategy);
        }

        if (consultSelect === '') {
            setFilteredConsult(...consult);
        }
    });

    const ShowUsers = (selectedDate) => {
        const result = filteredConsult.filter(
            (v) =>
                v.consult__availlability &&
                v.consult__users &&
                v.consult__date === selectedDate
        );

        setCurrentConsult(result[0].consult__users);
    };

    const onSelectChange = (event) => {
        setChecked({ selected: event.target.value });

        const selectedDate = event.target.value;

        consult && checked && ShowUsers(selectedDate);
    };

    return (
        <div className="consult__meetinplanner form-group">
            {loading !== true && <p>loading...</p>}
            {loading && consultSelect === '' && (
                <h3 style={{ marginTop: '2rem', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                    Maak een keuze aub.
                </h3>
            )}

            {filteredConsult &&
                filteredConsult.map((value, i) => {
                    const {
                        consult__date: date,
                        consult__time: time,
                        consult__availlability: is_available,
                    } = value;
                    return (
                        <div key={i} className="consult__results">
                            <label htmlFor={date}>
                                {is_available && (
                                    <div>
                                        <input
                                            type="radio"
                                            id={date}
                                            name={date}
                                            value={date}
                                            checked=""
                                            onChange={onSelectChange}
                                            disabled={props.disabled}
                                            required
                                        />
                                        <span>{date}</span>
                                        &nbsp; &mdash; &nbsp;
                                        <span>{time}</span>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

            {consultSelect !== '' &&
                currentConsult.map((user, i) => {
                    return (
                        <article key={user.consultation_user_item.nickname}>
                            <h4>{user.consultation_user_item.nickname}</h4>
                        </article>
                    );
                })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Appointment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goednmorgen Nino.

You are not binding checked prop to anything, here is an example how you can do this:

```js
function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState({
    selected: 'one',
  });
  const onSelectChange = (event) => {
    setChecked({ selected: event.target.value });

    // const selectedDate = event.target.value;

    // consult && checked && ShowUsers(selectedDate);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {['one', 'two', 'three'].map((value, index) => (
        <label key={index}>
          {value}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked.selected === value} //bind checked prop
            value={value}
            onChange={onSelectChange}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```